# Using an additional table in a MVVM Details View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm, detailsview, asp.net-mvc-controller

at the moment I have a OrderConfirmationController which has a Details view which displays the records. At the bottom of the Details View I want to add 5 fields from another table that will be displayed in the view but not sure how to add them.

At the bottom of the last table I want to implement a separate table containing the Product_ID, Description, Price, Quantity and Total from a Sales_Order_Line table but don't know how to add it as I can only reference one table using the @model at the start of the view.

Thanks.
Here is my code for the new class I have created:

```
class OrderConfirmation
{
    Sales_Order Bill_to_Customer_Name { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Bill_to_Address { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Bill_to_Address_2 { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Bill_to_City { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Bill_to_County { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Bill_to_Post_Code { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Bill_to_Country_Region_Code { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Ship_to_Contact_Name { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Ship_to_Address { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Ship_to_Address_2 { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Ship_to_City { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Ship_to_County { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Ship_to_Post_Code { get; set; }
    Sales_Order Ship_to_Country_Region_Code { get; set; }

    Sales_Order_Line Product_ID { get; set; }
    Sales_Order_Line Description { get; set; }
    Sales_Order_Line Price { get; set; }
    Sales_Order_Line Quantity { get; set; }
    Sales_Order_Line Total { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code for the Details controller:

```
        public ActionResult Details(string documentNo, int documentType)
    {
        ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line = Sales_Order_Line.Product_ID;
        ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line = Sales_Order_Line.Description;
        ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line = Sales_Order_Line.Price;
        ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line = Sales_Order_Line.Quantity;
        ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line = Sales_Order_Line.Total;

        // Compound key is used here so require both fields to be included in the SQL.
        Sales_Order confirmOrder = _data.Sales_Orders
           .Where(x => x.Document_Type == documentType && x.Document_No_ == documentNo)
           .FirstOrDefault();
        return View(confirmOrder);           
    }
```

And this is my View:

```
 @model SPR.Titanium.MultiChannel.ManagementConsolePortal.Models.OrderConfirmation
<link href="~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@section Scripts
{
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui");
<script src="~/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#accordion").accordion();
    })
</script>

}

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Order Confirmation Details";
}

<h2>Order Confirmation</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div id="accordion">
    <div class="editor-field">
        Billing Details:
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>

                <th style="width:20%">Billing Name</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model =>         model.Bill_to_Customer_Name)</td>
                <th style="width:20%">Address</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bill_to_Address).</td>
                <th style="width:20%">Address 2</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bill_to_Address_2).</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20%">City</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bill_to_City)</td>
                <th style="width:20%">County</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bill_to_County).</td>
                <th style="width:20%">Post Code</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bill_to_Post_Code)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20%">Country</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Bill_to_Country_Region_Code)</td>
            </tr>

        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        Delivery Details
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field" aria-readonly="true">
        <table style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20%">Delivery Name</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ship_to_Contact_Name)</td>
                <th style="width:20%">Address</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ship_to_Address)</td>
                <th style="width:20%">Address 2</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ship_to_Address_2)</td>
                </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20%">City</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ship_to_City)</td>
                <th style="width:20%">County</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ship_to_County)</td>
                <th style="width:20%">Post Code</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ship_to_Post_Code)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:20%">Country</th>
                <td style="width:30%">@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ship_to_Country_Region_Code)</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        @{
var line = (Sales_Order_Line)ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line;

    </div>
</div>
```

}

```
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Return to Sales Order List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that my first idea wouldn't work as I imagined. But you can use the ViewBag to pass additional values to the view:

Create a new class that has two properties, one of type Sales_Order and one of a class that contains the data from your other table. Use this new class as your @model and you can access them both.

```
class DetailsViewModel
{
    Sales_Order SalesOrder { get; set; }
    Sales_Order_Line { get; set; }
}
```

In your controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(string documentNo, int documentType)
{
    ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line = // get Sales_Order_Line object here

    ... // the rest of the code as before
}
```

In your view:

```
<div>
    @{
        var line = (Sales_Order_Line)ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line;
        ...
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Great but what would an example of the code for this look like? Bit of a novice you see. Thanks Daniel

Comment: Thanks for the reply @DanielSklenitzka I think I'm almost there but still a few concepts I don't understand so I'll edit my post above with the updated code as it'll be easier to view. Thanks - Nick.

Comment: I think I confused you with my earlier post. Get rid of the OrderConfirmation class and change it back to the older code.
And about the part with the ViewBag: That's just some syntactic sugar for using a dictionary. You're basically definining a new property in the ViewBag object with the Name Sales_Order_Line. With your current code, you're assigning a new value to this property in each of the 5 lines, overwriting the previous one. Just one line should be enough:

ViewBag.Sales_Order_Line = Sales_Order_Line;

Comment: The OrderConfirmation class has gone but still can't get the ViewBag to take the data from the other table to work so I can then display it in the View.

That one ViewBag line gives me the error that it is a "type but used like a variable"